# Type mismatch: LatLang Android Studio, kotlin development

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, google-maps

So i have this class LocationService where i define all the location related function but i'm encountering errors i can't get past by.
The errors are the following:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng but com.google.maps.model.LatLng! was expected on line 96

Type mismatch: inferred type is com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng but com.google.maps.model.LatLng! was expected on line 98

Unresolved reference: bounds on line 99
```

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.eventfinder.utils.LocationUtils
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds
import com.google.maps.GeoApiContext
import com.google.maps.PlacesApi
import com.google.maps.model.PlacesSearchResult
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import kotlin.math.*

class LocationService(private val context: Context) {
    private val fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    private val locationPermission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    private val apiKey = "Your API Key" // Replace with your API key

    interface LocationCallback {
        fun onLocationResult(location: Location?)
        fun onCitiesAndRegionsWithinRadiusResult(cityAndRegionNames: List<String>)
        fun onError(errorMessage: String)
    }

    fun getLastLocation(callback: LocationCallback) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            try {
                val location = retrieveLastLocation()
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    callback.onLocationResult(location)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    callback.onError("Error while retrieving location: ${e.message}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun retrieveLastLocation(): Location? {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, locationPermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (LocationUtils.isLocationEnabled(context)) {
                return try {
                    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.await()
                } catch (exception: Exception) {
                    throw Exception("Error while retrieving location: ${exception.message}")
                }
            } else {
                throw Exception("Location services are not enabled.")
            }
        }
        throw Exception("Location permission not granted.")
    }

    fun getCitiesAndRegionsWithinExtendedRadius(location: Location, extendedRadiusKm: Double, callback: LocationCallback) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            try {
                val cityAndRegionNames = lookupCitiesAndRegions(location, extendedRadiusKm)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    callback.onCitiesAndRegionsWithinRadiusResult(cityAndRegionNames.distinct())
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    callback.onError("Error while looking up cities: ${e.message}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun lookupCitiesAndRegions(location: Location, extendedRadiusKm: Double): List<String> {
        val maxRadius = 50000.0 // Maximum radius in meters (50 km)
        val center = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
        val geoContext = GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey(apiKey).build()
        val cityAndRegionNames = mutableListOf<String>()

        // Iterate in a circular pattern with a radius of 50 km each time
        var currentRadiusMeters = 0.0
        while (currentRadiusMeters < extendedRadiusKm * 1000) {
            // Determine the remaining radius to cover in this iteration
            val remainingRadiusMeters = min(maxRadius, (extendedRadiusKm * 1000 - currentRadiusMeters))

            // Calculate the circular boundary
            val bounds = getBounds(center, remainingRadiusMeters)

            // Perform the nearby search for this circular area
            val placesRequest = PlacesApi.nearbySearchQuery(geoContext, center)
                .radius(remainingRadiusMeters.toInt())
                .location(center)
                .bounds(
                    LatLng(bounds.southwest.latitude, bounds.southwest.longitude),
                    LatLng(bounds.northeast.latitude, bounds.northeast.longitude)
                )

            try {
                val placesResult = placesRequest.await()
                for (result: PlacesSearchResult in placesResult.results) {
                    for (type in result.types) {
                        if (type == "locality" || type == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                            cityAndRegionNames.add(result.name)
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                throw Exception("Error while looking up cities: ${e.message}")
            }

            // Move to the next circular area
            currentRadiusMeters += maxRadius
        }

        return cityAndRegionNames
    }

    private fun getBounds(center: LatLng, radiusMeters: Double): LatLngBounds {
        val latLngPerMeter = 1.0 / 111319.9 // Rough approximation for 1 meter
        val latLngRadius = radiusMeters * latLngPerMeter
        return LatLngBounds(
            LatLng(center.latitude - latLngRadius, center.longitude - latLngRadius),
            LatLng(center.latitude + latLngRadius, center.longitude + latLngRadius)
        )
    }
}
```

I got this code landed on my hands for me to fix it, but i rly can't figure it out, can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you imported from the wrong `package`.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
```

to

```
import com.google.maps.model.LatLng
```

---

Comment: wow, i found the problem
when i changed the import I got errors on another line. It seems the code has a mixed usage between classes of both imports. I have to rewrite some code with another logic.
Thanks a lot bro, i got there while changing the imports hahaha

Comment: You re welcome.